# How to implement an "isDebugEnabled" guard in Winston?

Tags: javascript, winston

In Java, the loggers typically provide a function that allows to skip unnecessary logging statements:

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
  logger.debug(/* ... some expensive operations ... */);
}
```

In JavaScript, I am using Winston, but did not find a similar API function.

This here is the best solution that I could come up with, but it looks a bit complicated:

```
const winston = require('winston');

if (winston.levels[winston.level] <= winston.levels.debug) {
  winston.debug(/* ... */);
}
```

Is there a simpler way?

---

I am aware that often the need for the guards can be eliminated. For instance this is from the Log4j documentation (Java):

```
logger.debug("Entry number: {} is {}", i, entry[i]);
```

But it will not solve all cases, for example, if `entry[i]` is replaced by an expensive function call, I would not assume that the compiler will be able to optimize it away.

Comment: For the record, if the logging interface in Java allows it, you can pass a lambda function, e.g., `logger.debug("Some result: {}", () -> expensiveComputationFunction())` that way `expensiveComputationFunction` will only be called on demand.

Comment: @vlaz Yes, something like that would also work for Winston. But I did not see such an option.

Comment: I'm unfortunately not familiar with Winston, so I cannot offer advise. I just thought I'd throw in the tip for Java logging. It doesn't always work, though - I remember I used some logging interface that didn't allow for lambdas to be passed in, so you still needed to surround them with `if (logger.isDebugEnabled())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update (2022-02-24):** On Aug 27, 2018 (shortly after the question and answer was posted), official support was added: version 3.1.0 introduced [support for isDebugEnabled](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/pull/1352).

The remaining answer contains the original workaround, but in newer versions it should be no longer necessary.

---

Finally, I ended up with this helper function:

```
function isDebugLogEnabled() {
  return winston.levels[winston.level] <= winston.levels.debug;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Winston 3.1.0 ([PR](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/pull/1352)), the `Logger` has built-in functions `isLevelEnabled(string)` & `isXXXEnabled()` for this.